# SAS-Generating Mean of a Variable For Each Date in Data Set

Tags: sas, data-processing

Hello I have a data set,  icecreamData that is of the form:

`Date         Firm      ConesSold

19900101        A             5
19900101        B             6
19900101        C             7
19900102        A             3
19900102        B             7
19900102        C             14`

and the data continues on for these three firms (A, B and C) until the end of 1990 (date is in yymmdd form) . I would like to create a new data set called iceCreamDataAverages that contains the date and the average number of cones
sold across all firms on that date. So the new data set should look like:

`Date         ConesSold

19900101        6
19900102        8`

I would also like to make another similar table that takes the median of ConesSold across firms for a given date.

My knowledge of SAS is quite limited, I thank you in advance.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the date a datetime field, or is it just 19900101 as a number?

Comment: It is a datetime field. The only thing I've been able to do is create a table for each date with the corresponding average but then I'd have to create 365 tables (one for each day) which obviously is a poor way to go about solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be solved simply using [proc means](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1qnc9bddfvhzqn105kqitnf29cp.htm).

```
proc means data = iceCreamData Mean;
class Date;
var ConesSold;
output out = iceCreamDataAverages mean(ConesSold)=MeanConesSold;
run;
```

If you wanted medians, simply swap out the `Mean(ConesSold)` for `Median(ConesSold)`. If this isn't working, then you may want to start looking at [proc timeseries](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_timeseries_sect003.htm), which is designed for dealing with data such as yours.